# Error: spawn ${/usr/lib/jvm/default-java}/bin/java ENOENT

Tags: java, json, debugging, visual-studio-code

```
Failed to start the program, Error: spawn ${/usr/lib/jvm/default-java}/bin/java ENOENT
```

This is the error i am facing while debugging my java code using Visual-Studio Code.

[This is how error looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iIuT.png)

Well my program name is ***sample.java*** and it is stored in ***~/Desktop/Data/VScode*** directory.I am working on ***Ubuntu 16.04LTS***.
and Java version is ***oracle JDK-9.0.1***

This is my **launch.json** file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${/usr/lib/jvm/default-java}/bin",
            "cwd": "$~/Desktop/Data/VScode",
            "startupClass": "${sample}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${~/Desktop/Data/VScode}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Java Console App",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "jdkPath": "${/usr/lib/jvm/default-java}/bin",
            "cwd": "${~/Desktop/Data/VScode}",
            "startupClass": "${sample}",
            "classpath": [
                ".",
                "${~/Desktop/Data/VScode}"
            ],
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

and This is my ***task.json*** file

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Compile Java",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "javac -g sample.java",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```